# Align two float actions button side by side

Tags: android

a bit of newbie here. I'm trying to align two float action buttons side by side but they are a bit overlapping.
Probabilly a sort of margin is needed, i tried with layout_marginRight="85dp" but it doesnt work.

**Screenshot**

[image: one]

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_user_profile" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_chat_white_24dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="left|center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_add_white_24dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How to get them viewing correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say it's not a good experience to put two FloatingActionButton side by side.Normally put one FAB or try to add a menu on it.
See this:https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

Comment: Thank you Inso for the answer, you are right saying that this is not the best UI experience suggested by Google, and in fact the Clans library solves my problem, but actually I prefer to show the two buttons side by side because the actions proposed to the user are immediately visible instead of require him to click on the plus '+' to discover those actions. Moreover with the MrLys solution I don't need to add any external library. Am I wrong?

Comment: Ok, I tested the other solution, and appears that two float actions button side by side are just ugly. Maybe I will add the buttons on the appbar itself as menu items.

Answer (score 1):

The best way, that I could find, was to encapsulate the two FABs in a RelativeLayout, like so:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_chat_white_24dp"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_add_white_24dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The RelativeLayout will have the same height as the FABs, so you don't have to think about height-alignment. The FABs will align at the right side, because of this line:

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

You might want to adjust the the margin values in each layout to match your needs. I think this should answer your question.

EDIT:
The above will not work as you intended. This will:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_person_add_white_24dp"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_person_add_white_24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Explanation

I now use the

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

as an anchor for the RelativLayout, which contains the FABs.

Removed `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` from the RelativeLayout and replaced it with `app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"` and `app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"`.

Still need to adjust the margins to your needs. Also I added `android:layout_height="85dp"` to your AppBarLayout, because I did not have the `android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"`. Just replace that as well.
Hope this helps.

Comment: why not a  horizontal linearLayout ?

Comment: @k0sh would that work as intended? Wouldn't you then have to set a fixed margin to make them align to the right. `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" ` Doesn't work in LinearLayouts. But I'm interested to know how that would work, if you are certain that it would.

Comment: all you have to do is to set gravity="end" on the linearLayout and you should be fine, there are no need for any extra stuff.

Comment: @k0sh if that is the case, then that would be a better solution, yes.

Comment: Sorry, i just can't stand using RelativeLayout. #prefmatter

Comment: This solution works partially, with Linear Layout too, because there are coming up some problems with the shadows (they're cropped) and with the behaviour of the scroll (when the content is scrolled, just the bottom half of the icon is still visible). I think I will need to use Clans library as Inso suggested.